# _iDisplayStart reset to zero when sorts

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have using Jquery datatable. Consider i was in page number 5 when I sorts _iDisplayStart reset to 0 in oSettings object.

Is there any way to retain same page when I sorts?

Answer (score 0):

there is a [plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw) to avoid this mechanic ( haven't tested it and maybe deprecated ):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('.dataTable').dataTable()
      table.fnStandingRedraw();
  } );
```

[here](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/1102/idisplaystart-with-sorting) there is a post on the argument